# WebForm en C#, enviar POST desde evento Page_Load ¿algúna limitacion?

Tags: php, c#, post, webforms

Tengo una página de **login**, que carga el formulario de login por defecto, pero ademas si ésta página recibe un parámetro como querystring (login.aspx?param=valor) en el Page_Load estoy recogiendo ese valor para hacer un envío por POST a un servicio PHP y obtener una información que necesito.

No tengo manera de hacerlo funcionar, el servicio PHP funciona correctamente y me devuelve informacion (si defino los valores a mano), pero éste no recibe los valores por POST que le mando desde Page_Load y me pregunto ya si es posible que haya algún tipo de problema al hacer el POST durante el evento Load.

Por decir, el login.aspx y el servicio php estan en el mismo root y se tiene certificado instalado..

**Pongo aquí uso de Page_Load**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    siteroot = clsUtil.GetSiteRoot();

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        try
        {
            if (q.Contains("parametro"))
            {
                string urlCF = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["urlCFTest"].ToString();
                string _token = q["parametro"].ToString();
                if (_token != string.Empty)
                {
                    //formateamos la llamada para consulta
                    string url = "http://....." //url del servicio PHP
                    Token tk = GetAccessTokenPHP(url); //aqui se hace el GET y funciona
                    if(tk != null)
                    {
                        RootObject msg = GetUserPHP("http://url_servicio_php", tk, _token);//ESTO NO ENVIA LOS PARAMETROS POR POST     

                        if (msg.user != null)
                        {...
```

//Aquí metodo envio por POST

```
public static RootObject GetUserPHP(string requestUrl,Token tk,string token_id)
{
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        var postData = string.Format("token_id={0}&access_token={1}", Uri.EscapeDataString(token_id), Uri.EscapeDataString(tk.access_token));
        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();                
            RootObject UserInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseString);
            return UserInfo;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {            
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Te regresa algun error o simplemente lo hace bien y no te regresa nada?

Comment: ¿Sí sabes por qué utilizas `!Page.IsPostBack` ?

Comment: Es lo que me imaginaba, independientemente de que se use o no el ispostback ..entiendo entonces que este comportamiento de hacer un post mientras se esta cargando un webform no es correcto. Lo he solucionado con GET pero me gustaria saber cual sería el procedimiento óptimo para hacerlo con POST. He probado a hacerlo asíncrono pero no tengo claro que sea distinto de hacerlo síncrono (no funciona) si no se hace un postback.